# Ring $R= \mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^6-1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> i) Check whether $R$ is a finite ring or not.
>
> ii) Check whether $R$ has zero divisors.
>
> iii) Check whether $R$ has nilpotent elements.

i) The field $Z_3$={0,1,2} has 3 elements but as repetitions are possible while forming a polynomial for infinite times and power of x can also have infinitely possible positive integers thus $Z_3[x]$ is not a finite ring. Again as $Z_3$[x] is not finite so will not be R.

Please help rectify if I am wrong here and also need help for part ii) & iii).

Comment: what does quotient ring mean to you?

Comment: How many elements are in the following set? $$\left\{ \frac{1}{1}, \frac{2}{2}, \frac{3}{3}, \frac{4}{4}, \cdots \right\} $$

Comment: "as $Z_3[x]$ is not finite so will not be $R$" is poor wording. One interpretation is that you're saying that since $Z_3[x]$ isn't finite, it can't be $R$, which is true but irrelevant. The more likely interpretation is that you're saying that $Z_3[x]$ is infinite so $R$ must be infinite. This is a non sequitor though. Notice $\Bbb Z$ is an infinite ring and all of its quotient rings are finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i) Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, then by Euclidean Division, one can write
$$
f(x) = q(x)(x^6-1) + r(x)
$$
where $\deg(r(x)) < 6$. Also, $\overline{f} = \overline{r}$ in $R$. Hence,
$$
R \subset \{ \overline{r} : \deg(r(x)) < 6\}
$$
This set is finite (why?), and so $R$ is finite (You are right that $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is infinite though)

ii) Check that $(x^2-1)^3 = x^6 - 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. Can you use this to construct zero divisors in $R$?

iii) Again, use the above idea to construct nilpotent elements as well!

Comment: The set is finite because it can only have 7 elements. Minus infinity,0,1,2,3,4,5. Am i right?

Comment: No. The set has much more than 7 elements, and where are you getting $-\infty$ from?

Comment: yes sir, I got my mistake but then it was already 5 mins up so couldn't edit it. I realized that corresponding to degree 1 every element of degree multiple of 7 will belong to the same congruent class and similarly for every degree. At least am i right this time? And finally I couldn't prove that the set you are talking about is finite. So please help. Thank you

Comment: One more thing, The degree of a zero polynomial is $-\infty$

Comment: I think ($x^2$+1) + <$x^6$+> is a nil potency 3 and ($x^2$+1)$^2$ + <$x^6$+1> is of nil potency 2. Am i correct? And these two elements are also zero divisors.